# What is the equivalent of process.client in Nuxt for Blazor?

Tags: blazor, nuxt.js

I'm trying to determine if the code on a page is being executed on the server or on the client side. In Nuxt, I'd use `process.client` which returns a bool that indicates if it's running on the client or server. What is the equivalent in Blazor?

Comment: [`OperatingSystem.IsBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem.isbrowser?view=net-8.0) maybe

Comment: Wow. It worked, Thank you. I can't find the button to mark your comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OperatingSystem.IsBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem.isbrowser?view=net-8.0).